Does ML Kit support QR codes larger than 3kb?
Does anyone know if ML Kit supports QR codes encoding more than 3kb? I cannot find anything in the documentation.
Our use case:
We have an app designed for offline use. Most of our users have poor-to-no internet during business hours. So, they complete forms offline, and they are automatically pushed to the backend via a background task, when the user has internet later.
We have a client asking if it would be possible for two users to share offline submissions. For example, a producer completes a form to book a load. The driver comes to pick up a load. The producer needs to share the completed form with the driver, but neither have internet.
One user could have an Apple device, and the other an Android device. So, Airdrop is not an option. Nor is Bluetooth, since Apple does not allow data transfer to non-Apple products. With Apple's new NFC emulation, it may seem like a feasible option, but it is not, due to the data size restrictions of NFC.
So, we're considering QR codes. We can encode the form data in JSON and compress it, which keeps it under 3kb. However, as we add more features to the forms, the data could exceed 3kb.
Thank you!

"Nor is Bluetooth, since Apple does not allow data transfer to non-Apple products" this is untrue. The multi peer connectivity framework only works with Apple devices but Core Bluetooth is capable of communicating with any BLE compliant device.

This isn't really about MLKit, it's about QR codes in general.  The QR code format only allows about 3KB of data.  You can work around this to get more (you can encode a URL either as a full URL or as a code that can be sent as a parameter to a particular endpoint), but you can't put more than 3K of data into a QR code.  It doesn't matter what library you use to parse it.
(As an aside-  why would you use mlkit to read a QR code?  There are QR code reading libraries that are smaller, less complicated, and would perform better.  You don't use machine learning to read a QR code.  ML kit is more useful when you need things like face detection that actually do need machine learning).

I was hoping maybe there was another standard similar to QR code, but supported larger data sizes. I am using ML Kit because we use Capacitor. There is a plugin for ML Kit already made, which works fine for our use case. Better than writing our own.
